# How often is the Profile > Summary > Accounts section updated?

Tags: support, badges

I've been awarded [with my first goldie on Science Fiction & Fantasy](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/help/badges/37/famous-question?userid=7885) about 14 hours ago. And, though my [Stack Exchange profile's `accounts` tab](https://stackexchange.com/users/1584557/trejder?tab=accounts) is already updated (showing this glimmering pretty! :]), my Stack Overflow's [`Profile > Summary > Accounts` section](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1469208/trejder) isn't updated yet. And it still shows dully `2+12`, not the beautiful `1+2+12`.

All right, I'm joking (of course) with all this "glimmering" stuff and foolish self-pride! :] But, I'd like someone to feed my curiosity. Isn't thirteen hours enough to update metioned info section in Stack Exchange profile? Shouldn't it sync to Stack Exchange profile (already? in the same time?).

Comment: Oops! **Now** it is updated (after fourteen hours). But the question remains -- why these two aren't updated in the same time and why there's such quite long delay in update?

Comment: The answer is caching. The answer is always caching.

Comment: @CodyGray Reformulate your comment to an answer, if you want me to accept it and bring you some rep.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are several scripts that run on a schedule to calculate, aggregate, dispatch, award and delete stuff.

Due to the size of the data, the cost of queries and how fresh the data needs to be some of those scripts run on a low frequency, some only run once every 24 hours.

If you see a mismatch in data, either between pages of your profile, main and meta, the site leagues, cross-site data, always wait for 24 hours to make sure all possible scripts have run.

If after 24 hours data is not updated to reflect all changes it is worth reporting because in that case one or more jobs might have failed and needs to be looked into by a Site Reliability Engineer.